# Как сделать, чтобы при авторизации на сайте, данные отправлялись на другой сайт и заполняли форму?

Tags: javascript, telegram, данные

У меня есть сайт, который может отправлять данные и мне нужно чтобы эти данные вводились сюда https://my.telegram.org/auth и я мог с ними работать. Я не шарю, поэтому и спрашиваю, что мне нужно сделать, чтобы это как-то работало, даже если криво.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если коротко, то никак. Кроссдоменный запрос, Вы не можете вводить данные за пользователя на чужих сайтах. Это огромная дыра в безопасности.